# token meaning dependent on context

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex

I have a weird string syntax where the meaning of a
delimiter depends on context. In the following sample
input:

```
( (foo) (bar) )
```

the result is a list of two strings `["foo"; "bar"]`.
The outer pair of parenthesis enters list mode.
Then, the next pair of parentheses delimits the string.
Inside strings, balanced pairs of parentheses are to be
treated as part of the string.

Right now the lexer decides what to return depending
on a global variable `inside`.

```
{
  open Sample_parser
  exception Error of string
  let inside = ref false (* <= to be eliminated *)
}
```

The delimiters are parentheses. If the lexer hits an
opening parenthesis, then

- if `inside` is *false*, it emits an
  `Enter` token and `inside` is set to *true*.
- If `inside` is *true*, it switches to a string lexer
  which treats any properly nested pair of parentheses
  as part of the string. If the nesting level returns to
  zero, the string buffer is passed to the parser.

If a closing parenthesis is encountered outside a string,
a `Leave` token is emitted and `inside` is unset.

My question is: *How do I rewrite the lexer without
the global variable `inside`*?

Fwiw I use menhir but afaict the same would be true for
ocamlyacc.
(Sorry if this sounds confused, I’m really a newbie to
the yacc/lex approach.
I can express all the above without thinking as a PEG but I
haven’t got used to mentally keeping lexer and parser
separated.
Feel free to point out other issues with the code!)

Simple example: *sample_lexer.mll*

```
{
  open Sample_parser
  exception Error of string
  let inside = ref false (* <= to be eliminated *)
}

let lpar  = "("
let rpar  = ")"
let ws    = [' ' '\t' '\n' '\r']

rule tokenize = parse
  | ws    { tokenize lexbuf }
  | lpar  { if not !inside then begin
              inside := true;
              Enter
            end else begin
              let buf = Buffer.create 20 in
              String (string_scanner
                        (Lexing.lexeme_start lexbuf)
                        0
                        buf
                        lexbuf)
            end }
  | rpar  { inside := false; Leave }
and string_scanner init depth buf = parse
  | rpar  { if depth = 0 then begin
              Buffer.contents buf;
            end else begin
              Buffer.add_char buf ')';
              string_scanner init (depth - 1) buf lexbuf end }
  | lpar  { Buffer.add_char buf '(';
            string_scanner init (depth + 1) buf lexbuf }
  | eof   { raise (Error (Printf.sprintf
                           "Unexpected end of file inside string, pos %d--%d]!\n"
                           init
                           (Lexing.lexeme_start lexbuf))) }
  | _ as chr { Buffer.add_char buf chr;
               string_scanner init depth buf lexbuf }
```

*sample_scanner.mly*:

```
%token <string> String
%token Enter
%token Leave

%start <string list> process

%%

process:
  | Enter lst = string_list Leave { lst }

string_list:
  | elm = element lst = string_list { elm :: lst }
  | elm = element                   { [elm]      }

element:
  | str = String { str }
```

*main.ml*:

```
open Batteries

let sample_input = "( (foo (bar) baz) (xyzzy) )"
(*                  EibssssssssssssseibssssseiL
 * where E := enter inner
 *       L := leave inner
 *       i := ignore (whitespace)
 *       b := begin string
 *       e := end string
 *       s := part of string
 *
 * desired result: [ "foo (bar) baz"; "xyzzy" ] (type string list)
 *)

let main () =
  let buf = Lexing.from_string sample_input in
  try
    List.print
      String.print stdout
      (Sample_parser.process Sample_lexer.tokenize buf);
    print_string "\n";
  with
  | Sample_lexer.Error msg   -> Printf.eprintf "%s%!" msg
  | Sample_parser.Error      -> Printf.eprintf
                                    "Invalid syntax at pos %d.\n%!"
                                    (Lexing.lexeme_start buf)

let _ = main ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the state as an argument to `tokenize`. It still has to be mutable, but not global.

```
rule tokenize inside = parse
  | ws    { tokenize inside lexbuf }
  | lpar  { if not !inside then begin
              inside := true;
              Enter
            end else begin
              let buf = Buffer.create 20 in
              String (string_scanner
                        (Lexing.lexeme_start lexbuf)
                        0
                        buf
                        lexbuf)
            end }
  | rpar  { inside := false; Leave }
```

And you call the parser as follows:

```
Sample_parser.process (Sample_lexer.tokenize (ref false)) buf
```

Comment: This is indeed and impovement and answers the question. But is there a way to get rid of the pointer entirely?